# How to create a new project from an existing package in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am new to any IDEA and I am using IntelliJ recently.

I am asking if I have three classes in a package, one class contains the main method, I have opened this package in IntelliJ IDEA but the RUN icon is greyed out.

How could solve this problem or how could I create a project from this package?

[image]

Comment: Did you try to import the project from IntelliJ? Manually importing the project from the import option might resolve your problem although you might have to manually configure the JDK if you haven't done yet.

Comment: Make a new directory called Foo or something, add an src folder to it, and add your package to that, and then open Foo / your project directory in IntelliJ

Comment: Add a new module and define the content/source roots: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#add-new-module, https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-content-roots.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some IntelIJ products there is button to import the project.
Import means it will convert the project from other ide to IntelIJ project.

But it is not always possible. 
Usually you can open only projects created in that IDE.

You can create new project and create classes with same names, also pay attention to "Edit configuration" that is usually near Run button. In configuration you can specify which file you want to compile and run and what compiler you want to use.
For example, you want to run 'main' method of class Bounce.java using java version 1.8.